# Which function is called when transferring a NFT to another address

Tags: nft

this is my first question. I hope it doesnt sound dumb but I wanted to know when I have a NFT in my wallet, and send it to another address (with Metamask for example), will Metamask call the transfer() method of the smart contract where the NFT was minted, or of an address (if thats even possible). Is Ether itself just a smart contract on the blockchain?
I hope you get my question, its just an understanding-question but would help me alot.

Greetings
Luca

Comment: Idk if metamask support nfts, and it depends on the implementation of NFT so we need more information :/ . Sadly didn’t get your second part of the question but there is “Ether” which is not a smart contract but the native currency, and there is WEther which is a contract that lock ether and create equal weth tokens.

Comment: Thank you so much :) . Yes now I got the use case of WEther, its basically the native currence wrapped into a Contract. And yes thats the question, if the send Button in for example metamask depends on the implementation of the ERC721 Contract. For example metamask gets the abi of a smart contract, and on the send button it will always call the for example transfer() method in the ABI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically yes. It calls `approve(address to, uint256 tokenId)` or `safeTrafnsferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)` depending on situation
2. No. Ether is not a smart-contract it is a native currency. Though any other "coin" on the Ethereum blockchain is a smart-contract. Either it implements ERC20, or ERC721, or etc...